# How to use mask in vuetify text-field?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use the mask property of text-field component, like the example below. In the view, that works like a charm, but, when the form is posted, the mask format does not keep the value.

For example, when I type "000.000.000-00", the value that the form posted was "00000000000". How can I keep the format value?

```html
<v-text-field
  :value="currentValue" 
  @input="handleInput"
  :mask="###.###.###-##"/>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## In Vuetify 2 masks have been removed

---

#### Answer for Vuetify versions < 2.0.0

You can use `return-masked-value` prop

```
<v-text-field
    :value="currentValue" 
    return-masked-value
    mask="###.###.###-##"
    @input="handleInput"
></v-text-field>
```

---

Note that currently in `v0.17` [there is a bug](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/2722) with returning unmasked initial value.

Comment: mask is not suported and removed from library from vue 2.0.0

Comment: @zaqpiotr this related to Vuetify, not Vue itself. Vuetify is supporting mask:  
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#masks-using-vue-the-mask,  
https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#masks

Comment: @escapedcat zaqplotr is right. Seems there is a new addon vue-the-mask now!

Comment: apparently vuetify 2 really doesn't support masks for some reason.

Answer (score 22):

With Vuetify 2 they removed the mask attribute. However, there is a third-party solution. You can use the lightweight package [v-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-mask) by [probil](https://github.com/probil/v-mask):

Install the v-mask package (unpacked size 71.7 kB)

```sh
npm install v-mask
```

In your **main.js** import the package and add it as a directive:

```js
import { VueMaskDirective } from 'v-mask'
Vue.directive('mask', VueMaskDirective);
```

Then in your component add the mask using `v-mask`:

```html
<v-text-field
  v-mask="'###.###.###-##'"
  :value="currentValue" 
  @input="handleInput"
/>
```

Comment: How to get unmasked value from this?

Comment: @AhmadBudairi it does not appear to be possible at this time: https://github.com/probil/v-mask/issues/42