# How to use mask in a Combobox component with Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to use the mask property for validating the input before it can be added to the list of selected items.

**Code:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    select: ''
  })
})
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-combobox
          v-model="select"
          label="Add 3 digit numbers"
          multiple
          chips
          mask="###"
        ></v-combobox>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**Problem:**

Now the result is the mask limit the length of the input but not the format and then when an element is added Vue throws an error

> the value is read as string and is sliced character by character.

**Objective:**

My goal is that the user **only can add values that match the mask**.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a Codepen with the same code for better understanding https://codepen.io/pepas_24/pen/ejbJbd

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857673/how-to-use-mask-in-vuetify-text-field?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

There is bug in Vuetify when using the mask attribute with multiple.  Remove multiple and it will work.

Comment: I tried this, but I need add multiple values so this don't help me :/